# Just installed 13.04, but I can't save anything - says disk is full!

Tags: vmware

I just finished installing 13.04 as a virtual machine using vmware 6.

For some reason it says the disk is full, and I can't save any file no matter how small the change is.

When I check the disk size using the native vista os, it reports 7.63 GB free on the partitioned drive where the VM is installed, and 4.47GB free on the main hard drive.

I have previously used ubuntu10.10 installed in the same way without this problem.

any suggestions?

Comment: How much space you have on the host OS does not matter, it is how much space you allocated to the vm.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the case that you have many small files installed and not enough inodes on your filesystem.
You can check this with

```
df -i
```

If you have enough inodes left, you should check your free space with

```
df
```

Note: Both inside of your Ubuntu installation, run these from the console/shell prompt.